# How to check if the entered value is in a key - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, authentication

I've been trying to create a really simple login screen on python for fun. Somewhere else in the program I have it save the entered username and password as a str (in dict format) on an external file. I can get it to check if the key-username- is correct but i cant find a way to make it check if the password entered is the password linked with the key -the value- I might of worded this weirdly but does any one have any idea how?

```
def login():
clear()
gap()
loginu = input("ENTER YOUR USERNAME:")
gap()
file = open("usernamesf.txt","r")
usernra = file.read()
usernr = usernra.replace("'","")
usernw = '"{' + usernr + '}"'
print (usernw)
usernwl = ast.literal_eval(usernw)
print (usernwl)
if loginu in usernwl:
    gap()
    loginp = input("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD:")
    loginpc = usernw[loginu]
    if loginp in loginpc:
        print ("yay")

else:
    gap()
    print ("NO USERNAME FOUND...")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    gap()
    signu = input("Would you like to sign up?")
    if signu in ['yes','y','Y','Yes',' yes',' Yes',' y',' Y']:
        sign()
    else:
        menu()
```

Comment: if key in dict:
    return dict[key] == password

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend that you use the `json` library to parse your file - it is able to convert python dictionaries to string and vice versa, which is really useful.

To convert `dict` to `str`: 
`json.dumps(dictionary)`

To convert `str` to `dict`: `json.loads(string)`

With this, to read the dictionary from the file, it is simply:

```
import json
with open("usernamesf.txt") as f:
     user_dictionary = json.loads(f.read())
     if loginu in user_dictionary:
         password = input("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD")
         if user_dictionary[username] == password:
             # success
```

Notice how i used the `with` statement here for the file - this ensures that the file is properly closed by python after you are done with it - that is, after you exit the `with` block. You can read more about this in the official python documentation on file I/O here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects